# Creating a shapefile with accumulated discharges in ArcMap 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, hydrology

I have a shapefile which represents a waterbody (first picture) and I have a point shapefile which shows the location of discharges  (second picture). Is it possible to create from these datas a shapefile which accmululates the discharge values in flow direction (like the third picture)?

waterbody
[image: Waterbody]

discharge Points
[image: Waterbody with entry points]

accumulated discharge
[image: acculmulated shapefile]

Comment: How did you get your discharge at each point? Do you have a Flow Accumulation grid? DEM? It certainly isn't impossible to do, but it varies how hard it is to get there depending on your original data.

Comment: The basis of these discharge points is a DEM from which i calculated the flowdirection and flowaccumulation. So I should have all the datas I need.

Comment: The colouring in your image implies that you have summed up your discharge values for each line, is that what you want? Otherwise you would need to do something similar to what @Martin suggests and fragment up your network so you can assign each segment the value of the point.

Comment: Yes I want to summarize the single discharges in flow direction. I´m currently trying Martins solution but I stuck on creating a centerline  for my polygon waterbody.

Comment: Have a look at ETGeowizards (www.ian-ko.com), there are a few functions that probably can help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have points that overlap the drainage lines, and that these points have relevant discharge (flow accumulation) in the attribute table. There are multiple ways to do this, but here's one:

- Split your drainage lines at the points, and create unique ID's for the line segments.
- Create a [Spatial join](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm) with your points and line segments. Each (most) of the lines will overlap two points, so chose Many to One so you get both points' value to the new attribute table.
- [Dissolve](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm) by fields with the unique ID. Use the statistics section to extract MAX values from the Discharge field for each line segment.

There are alternative ways to do this as well, like extracting cell values from the Flow accumulation grid to your line segments and chose maximum value.